# Forward remote control port with iptable

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, forwarding

I have the folowwing scenario is the router who forward to iptable the remote control to a MS Server 2008 nevertheless i haven't been able to make it work with the current iptable rule i have:
[image]

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3389 --destination 192.168.0.5
-A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 3389 --destination 192.168.0.5
```

192.168.0.5 is the address of the MS Server, so i try to redirect the request to it. Any suggestion.

**Edit**

this is what /etc/init.d/iptable status throws with 3389 grp

```
10   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.0.5         tcp dpt:3389
113  ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 21,25,110,1143,143,2082,2095,2525,3306,3389,7080,7777
11   DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            190.181.129.51      tcp dpt:3389 to:192.168.0.5:3389
12   DNAT       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            190.181.129.51      udp dpt:3389 to:192.168.0.5:3389
```

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d <IP_OF_YOUR_ROUTER> --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.5:3389
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.0.5 --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: try it but still doesnt work any suggestion to approach this?

Comment: If you're using an IP Forward rule, verify that /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward is set to 1. This can be set in /etc/sysctl.conf (look for net.ipv4.ip_forward) or with the sysctl command also.

Comment: it is set 1 ...

Comment: why -d <IP_OF_YOUR_ROUTER> and not of my firewall ip address isnt the destiny address?

Comment: it should be your firewall. Try it with that ip.

Comment: nothing this is getting frustating the router forward to the iptable >  iptable > MS 2008 but this is not happening... any insight how to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Try executing this script : -

```
    #!/bin/bash

    #Uncomment the following line to enable ip forwarding if it is not already enabled.
    #echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

    #nat rules to change destination ip address to the ip address of MS server
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d <IP Address of the router/machine on which you are planning to execute this script> --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.5


    #Allow response from MS server to router/machine on which you execute this script 
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.0.5 -j MASQUERADE
```

If the above script does not work, clear the above rules and try the following script : -

```
    #!/bin/bash

    #Uncomment the following line to enable ip forwarding if it is not already enabled.
    #echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

    #nat rules to change destination ip address to the ip address of MS server
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d <IP Address of the router/machine on which you are planning to execute this script> --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.5:3389


    #Allow response from MS server to router/machine on which you execute this script 
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.0.5 -j MASQUERADE
```